# Understanding this snippet 'D' * (num % 1000 / 500)

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain how to read this code and what it will do?

```
'D' * (num % 1000 / 500)
```

It is from a method for converting integers to Roman numerals. I don't understand how it functions.

Comment: Put the code in the question body. Which part of `'D' * (num % 1000 / 500)` don't you understand?

Comment: What is `num`? .................

Comment: Another way to express this is `num % 1000 < 500 ? '' : 'D'`

Comment: Since Roman numerals are upto 5000 in value, can one create a hash of all possible roman numerals and use that for conversion?

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty obfuscated indeed. I guess the idea was to put *one or zero* `D`s depending on if you get a number greater than 500 after you get the remainder of division by 1000.

The order of the operations:

```
num % 1000
```

`num` modulo 1000. Will leave the last three digits.

```
/ 500
```

Will see if the last three digits are greater than 500.

[String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-2A) repeats a string:

```
'x' * 5 # => "xxxxx"
```

---

The reason that is needed is because `D` is the letter for 500. You will have only *one or zero* of these as `M` is the letter for 1000.

Answer (score 3):

The expression (num % 1000 / 500) means "if you have in your last 3 digits a number greater than 500 then evaluate to 1 otherwise evaluate to 0"

"D" * (0 or 1) is determining whether to put "D" on the roman number or not.

Answer (score 3):

**What it Does**

The expression is a way of building the Roman numeral five-hundreds digit, which is 'D'.

It takes any number, extracts only the three rightmost digits (values 0 through 999), and returns a `'D'` *only* if the value is 500 or greater. Otherwise it returns an empty string `''`

**How to Read it**

In Ruby, the multiply `*`, divide `/`, and modulus `%` symbols have equal precedence and are processed in order from left to right. Parentheses, however, have a higher precedence than these three operators.

To help visualize the processing order, you can add optional parentheses:

```
'D' * ( ( num % 1000 ) / 500 )
```

1. num % 1000:

   - extracts the three rightmost digits of a number, resulting in values 0 - 999
2. {0-999} / 500:

   - determines if value is 500 or greater, or not.
   - Returns 1 if so, 0 if not.
   - In Ruby, integer division does not automatically convert to decimals.
3. 'D' * {1 or 0}:

   - In Ruby, [multiplying a string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2A) by 1 returns the string, multiplying by 0 returns an empty string

**Examples**

For a number 35,045:

```
35045 % 1000  #=> 45
45 / 500      #=> 0
'D' * 0       #=> ""
```

For a number 468,987:

```
468987 % 1000 #=> 987
987 / 500     #=> 1
'D' * 1       #=> "D"
```

For a number 670:

```
670 % 1000    #=> 670
670 / 500     #=> 1
'D' * 1       #=> "D"
```

For a number 7:

```
7 % 1000      #=> 7
7 / 500       #=> 0
'D' * 0       #=> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) page and scroll down to Ruby Operators Precedence.

Multiplication, division, and modular arithmetic are all together, so precedence is left to right IIRC.

First, `num % 1000` is evaluated. Then, that is divided by `500`. That's then multiplied by 'D'.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus `%` and division `/` operators have the same precedence.

So *associativity*, which is from left to right for these operators, comes into play.

Therefore the expression is equivalent to `'D' * ((num % 1000) / 500)`: you are multiplying 'D' by the last 3 digits of `num` divided by 500.